# Background image in columns of graph

Tags: perl, cgi, gd

I have cgi-script that draws a graph. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use CGI ':standard';
use GD::Graph::bars;
use strict;

my @data = (["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
             "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
            [23, 5, 2, 20, 11, 33, 7, 31, 77, 18, 65, 52]);

my $mygraph = GD::Graph::bars->new(500, 300);
$mygraph->set(
    x_label => 'Month',
    y_label => 'Number of Hits',
    title   => 'Number of Hits in Each Month in 2002',
    dclrs   => ['cyan']
) or warn $mygraph->error;

my $myimage = $mygraph->plot(\@data) or die $mygraph->error;

print "Content-type: image/png\n\n";
print $myimage->png;
```

All the columns are cyan color. So...

Have you got any ideas how can I place image in columns instead of color?

I searched the web about it but nothing similar I couldn't find.
I would like to use only GD.pm without using additional modules such as ImageMagick.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know. You can have a background image for the entire graph by specifying the logo option.

```
$mygraph->set(
    x_label => 'Month',
    y_label => 'Number of Hits',
    title   => 'Number of Hits in Each Month in 2002',
    dclrs   => ['cyan'],
    logo => 'mydog.png',
) or warn $mygraph->error;
```

But I don't think you can put an image in only the columns.

Comment: Anyway thanks for the answer. Maybe GD doesn't allow to do such tricks.